# Cannot find symbol in Java array

Tags: java, arrays

[image]

This is my code, but the system said

> cannot find symbol in this code "`Book[ ] books = new Book[size];`".

How I can fix it?

Comment: Can you provide full code ?

Comment: Don't provide code as an image, provide it as text.

Comment: The only reason for that error is that there is no `Book` class. If you have defined one in a different package, you need to import it.

Comment: Do you have a class called `Book`?  Is it in the same package as the class that you've shown here?  If not, do  you know how an `import` statement works?

Comment: Where is the Book class defined?

Comment: please add code directly don't use images..

Answer (score 1):

at file start, you are probably missing a:

```
import something.something.Book;
```

in eclipse, go to error line, control+1, Import ... (first item of popup item).
Otherwise, you are missing the whole `Book` class:

```
class Book {
    private String title;
    private int isbn;
    private int quantity;

    public Book(String title, int isbn, int quantity) {
        this.title = title;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: I try to import it but it said "package something.something does not exist"

Comment: yeah, "something.something" was a placeholder, you must put there the name of the package your class is in (first line of the file you posted says something like package "*something.something*";)